# How to check if a .mp4 file is not corrupt and not missing movie frames or audio segments programmatically

Tags: php, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

With youtube-dl I was able to download quite a couple of .mp4 files. However, I have just discovered, after manually playing some of them, that they are missing movie frames in some parts while still playing audio (so a blank screen is shown), or missing audio while still playing movie frames.

Hence,
(1) Why doesn't youtube-dl detect or warn against such a scenario? It looks like the movie segments and audio track were merged and .mp4 produced without any warning. Is there a way to configure youtube-dl to detect such cases and redownload the movie?
(2) Otherwise, are there other ways to detect such cases programmatically? (considering that one might have thousands of such .mp4 files and may not be able to manually go thru all of them?) A solution with FFmpeg or php will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of that is possibly youtube-dl skipped (some) fragments when it had been downloading the file, there are things you can do to prevent this if you're using terminal/command prompt, some of them are:

- To use --fragment-retries RETRIES options, be careful when using the 'infinite', if the fragment is lost on the server-side, your code will end up doing an infinite loop

  > --fragment-retries infinite
- Or enable the --abort-on-unavailable-fragment flag, to abort when youtube-dl detects the problematic fragments

  > --abort-on-unavailable-fragment

That should prevent any future videos/audios to have a broken fragment, read more [here](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl)

> NOTE: I'm currently looking for a way to detect downloaded videos whether it's broken or not (i.e. fragment lost, etc.)